# Regex NSRegularExpression vs NSPredicate

Tags: ios, regex, swift3

I was using a function to validate email format and password up till now

```
func isRegexValid(string:String,regex:String) -> Bool {
   return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex).evaluate(with: string)
}
```

I was trying to check a certain pattern and ran into problems. I was looking to find a string with 4 comma delimiters followed by "ext"

```
^(.*,){4}ext
```

The above function would not handle this as expected, so I tried an alternative which works well

```
func isRegexValid2(string:String,pattern:String) -> Bool {
  let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
  return regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count)) != nil
}
```

I would like to understand the differences between the two regex calls and whether we should avoid one or the other.

Comment: You probably should use `^([^,]*,){4}ext` instead.

Comment: the problem may be due to `.` which matches also `,` (first)  and pattern will match first four fields only after backtracking

Answer (score 5):

NSPredicate is very different from NSRegularExpression.

NSPredicate is used for searching and filtering among the Cocoa object. Its primary purpose is to filter certain object among a collection of objects. It has a completely different syntax.

As mentioned in the Apple docs for NSPredicate

> Predicates represent logical conditions, which you can use to filter collections of objects.

For further study you can see [Predicate programming guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

On the other hand NSRegularExpression is a class that is used to compile regular expressions that are then applied to unicode strings.

NSRegularExpression class supports standard ICU regular expression defined at http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Hope this clarifies.